# How to project an image with gdalwarp to cover a Mapbox map?

Tags: gdalwarp, mapbox-gl-js, web-mercator

I'm trying to re-project a geographical raster source covering entire world (temperature data from GFS) to Web Mercator with this command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 input.grib output.tif
```

However, placing it as overlay over a Mapbox map shows a shift in latitude.

[image]

Original bounds: top left 0d 7'30.00"W, 90d 7'30.00"; bottom right 359d52'30.00"E, 90d 7'30.00"S

Original image dimensions: 1440x721

Projected bounds: top left 179d59'59.12"W, 81d 6'45.00"N; bottom right 179d52'20.79"E, 81d 6'38.83"S

Projected image dimensions: 1249x1016

Inspecting the output image shows that gdalwarp returned data within ~81° latitude bound, instead of expected ~85° as defined by [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) spec. It seems this is the cause of my original issue.

What would be the correct gdalwarp params, so that the output image covers a Mapbox map?

The original file can be accessed at https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl , select any date and time, file with f000 suffix, check level 2 m above ground, variable TMP, download.